# Can't upload file from browser. RobotFramework, Selenium + Autoit on remote host

Tags: selenium, autoit, robotframework

I have read many posts with similar problem but I didn't find any solution.
In my tests I'm uploading some files - after click on button in app in browser system shows window 32770 (opening or browse). I'm using AutoIt library for RobotFramework to handle upload action by this system window. Everything works perfectly until I run it on remote hosts (windows slave computer) and terminal's screen is covered. 
Has anybody met and solved such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of uploading files with Selenium2Library is to use the [Choose File](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File) keyword, which bypasses the need to interact with a popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this**

> choose file(locator,Path)
>
> locator: Location of element where you click to upload image
>
> Path: Path of image

Put your image is working directory.